# Questions about refreshing TextView

Tags: android, loops, textview

I am building a simple game (using Java and android xml) and I want to refresh a TextView with a numeric value as often as possible (let's say 5-10 times a second)

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to show a numeric value refreshing more than once a second?
2. How to do it efficiently?

My current code:

```
void textViewRefresher() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                                format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);

                                bankValue = bankValue + 0.1 * perSecondValue;
                                String truncatedBank = format.format(bankValue);
                                bankText.setText(truncatedBank);

                                totalValue = totalValue + 0.1 * perSecondValue;
                                String truncatedTotal = format.format(totalValue);
                                totalText.setText("Total: " + truncatedTotal);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: You can use a `Handler` or `Timer` as well. Comment if you want an example.

Comment: I think your current code is fine

Comment: invalidate view did u try ?

Comment: @Kurlicue It works, but browsing the internet I found information that it's inefficient, so I was wondering if there is some better approach.

Comment: @MalithLakshan Can you try to tell me which approach is best/most efficient?

Comment: That depends. Most people recommend using a Handler. Do some online research and you will find the best match for you. PS Don't just agree with what somebody says in a blog. Implement the available methods and look how your app behaves. @PawelJezierski

Comment: You can use ValueAnimator (with e.g. an IntEvaluator) and a custom ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener. Pass the TextView which has to be modified to the Listener via its constructor. Override `onAnimationUpdate()` to set the new text. See the docs: [Animating with ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#value-animator)